# Protect Oracle database server and Listener from distributed denial-of-service(DOS) attack

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

`Hello`,  
I'm finding for best practices and adequate steps to secure oracle server 11G Enterprise edition and network listener from malicious clients. 
Any ****recommendations**?** Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Malicious clients can attempt to flood database servers with connect requests that consume resources. This is a possible scenario for a distributed DoS attack**.

---

To prevent this scenario, use the `SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` in the
`sqlnet.ora` file and INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_listener_name parameters in conjunction.

`SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` should be set to a value in seconds and
it determines how long a client has to provide the necessary authentication information to a database because it is possible for connections without authentication to stay open indefinitely.

It is also recommended to set a value for the `INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_listenername` parameter in the `listener.ora` file to determine how long a client has to complete its connect request to the listener after the network connection has been established.

Then database server terminates the connection if the client fails to establish a connection and complete authentication within the time limit. Therefore, to protect both the database server and the listener, **Oracle recommends** setting
both these parameters in combination.